# Particle System > Advanced > Rotation Orientation Axis = Not Working

Tags: particles

Please see the attached screenshots and project file. For some reason I cannot randomize the rotation of my particles along only the X/Y axis, even though Z is set as the Orientation Axis.  Is this a glitch?

Note that this is using the default cube, no changes have been made to it.

Project File:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/yfq38ryg3ih2jwx/z_up.blend?dl=0

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want that the cube is only rotated on the z axis (randomly) you have to change it to these settings and you will get: (just push up the randomize value)

[image]

This is the result for just randomizing the x axis:

[image]

Comment: Thank yo so much Chris!  I was losing my mind over this.  I played with all of these values so many times I got lost, and I never slid the Randomize Phase value up while the Randomize value was at 0.  I'm sure there is a good reason why Randomize isn't the one that would do this, but at this point I expect these kinds of weird confusions with Blender and take it all with a grain of salt ;)

Comment: Glad I could help